# Extracting maximum SQL

Tags: sql, max

Query:

```
select 
    c1.cname, c2.sumlength as totallength 
from 
    country c1 
JOIN 
    (select 
         country, sum(length) as sumlength 
     from 
         neighbour 
     group by 
         country 
     order by 
         sum(length)) c2 ON c1.cid = c2.country;
```

Output:

```
    cname    | totallength 
-------------+-------------
 San Marino  |          39
 Albania     |         605
 Lesotho     |         909
 Afghanistan |        5529
 Algeria     |        6343
```

I want to extract the maximum of the total length and the cname.

Desired output:

```
    cname    |     max
-------------+------------- 
 Algeria     |        6343
```

I tried executing:

```
select 
    c1.cname, max(c2.sumlength) as totallength 
from 
    country c1 
JOIN 
   (select 
        country, 
        sum(length) as sumlength 
    from 
        neighbour 
    group by 
        country 
    order by 
        sum(length)) c2 ON c1.cid = c2.country;
```

But I keep encountering this error:

> ERROR:  column "c1.cname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Need to add 'GROUP BY c1.cname'  at the end

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY C2.sumlength DESC) rn,
                c1.cname,
                c2.sumlength                 AS totallength
         FROM   country c1
                JOIN neighbour c2
                  ON c1.cid = c2.country
                JOIN (SELECT country,
                             Sum(length) AS sumlength
                      FROM   neighbour
                      GROUP  BY country) c2
                  ON c1.cid = c2.country)
SELECT cname,
       totallength
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**SAMPLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
  (cname       VARCHAR(50),totallength INT
  )

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES      ('San Marino',39),('Albania',605),
            ('Lesotho',909),('Afghanistan',5529),
            ('Algeria',6343);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY totallength DESC) rn,
                cname,
                totallength
         FROM   #temp)
SELECT cname,
       totallength
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: That still returns me the same output.

Comment: @user3291818 still you are getting the same Error ??

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
 select top1
        c1.cname, c2.sumlength as totallength 
    from 
        country c1 
    JOIN 
        (select 
             country, sum(length) as sumlength 
         from 
             neighbour 
         group by 
             country 
         order by 
             sum(length)) c2 ON c1.cid = c2.country;
         order by c2.sumlength desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try :-

```
SELECT
    *
FROM country AS X
WHERE X.totalLength IN (
    SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT, totalLength))
    FROM country AS Y
)
```

your example :-

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'San Marino' AS cName, 39 AS totalLength
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Albania', 605
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Lesotho', 909
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Afghanistan', 5529
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Algeria', 6343
) AS X
WHERE X.totalLength IN (
    SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT, totalLength))
    FROM (
        SELECT 'San Marino' AS cName, 39 AS totalLength
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Albania', 605
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Lesotho', 909
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Afghanistan', 5529
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Algeria', 6343
    ) AS Y
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
with data as (select 
         country, sum(length) as sumlength 
     from 
         neighbour 
     group by 
         country)
select * from data where sumlength=(select max(sumlength) from data)
```

This should work for most of the standard DBMS since you did not tell us, which DB you use.

Another approach would be to order the result set and only deliver the first row using **top** or **limit**. This depends on the DBMS you use.